# Alternate and Simple Styles for mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Are there alternate styles available for the material data table (mat-table)?

I don't mean the ones that come with the pre-built themes, I mean styles like table-striped, table-sm, or table-bordered in bootstrap 4.

Or is it all up to the author to work within the theme styles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's up to the author to implement any special styling. I'm not familiar with what those bootstrap table styles look like, but things like borders or alternating row background colors would be fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @G.Tranter .  I don't find it that easy because of how the existing styles work with changes I have tried so far. But if there is nothing that comes "out of the box" and no reference to see what comes "in the box," then I will keep experimenting. Thanks again!

Comment: The examples they provide are poor, but the component works well.

Comment: Agreed. I have had no problem once, I cracked the code of how to get the component working, with the use nor the sorting, but styling it has been a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can add simple styles to the `mat-table`
Please refer to this question.

[How to apply some style to the table row in angular material table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370523/how-to-apply-some-style-to-the-table-row-in-angular-material-table)